# Is subclassing a python class to change the initialiser the best pattern to use?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, factory

I'm designing a library with a fairly powerful class - we can think of it as a list.

I'm expecting users to want to create their own lists, prepopulated with certain content. For the sake of example, things like "add n identical items to the list", or "initialise with the numbers from a->b". Note that these things don't really change how the list works, they just set it up in some complex way.

The users will need to use these from different bits of code, be able to reuse them in the future.

I can see two possible ways for the users to do this:

Create a function which builds the object for them, e.g.:

```
def make_item_list(n,x):
    ls = [x]
    ls *= n
    return ls
```

Or, alternatively, subclass the list to add an initialiser:

```
class RepeatList(List):
    def __init__(self,n,x):
        super().__init__()
        self.listitems = [x]*n
```

Clearly this is a toy example but which of these is more sensible and 'pythonic'? If there are other patterns in Python to do this, what are they? If the choice of pattern depends on something else I haven't mentioned, what is it and how would it influence decision making? I'm happy to provide more info if you need it. Thank you!

Comment: The function, IMO. But really, you should just add alternative constructors as classmethods to your class, that would be the most idiomatic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. The issue is that I'm defining the class (writing a library) that will be distributed to other people to use. They will be the people wanting to add the extra initialisers, so they can't be baked in by me.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking in that case. Then it's really up to them, no?

Comment: Correct, it is up to them. However there's two reasons I'm asking: A) I will need to write sample code to guide them, and I'd like to know the best way to suggest they approach this common task. And B) if there are design decisions I can make during the creation of the library that make this task easier for them, then I would like to know them.

Comment: Your RepeatList() is not a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most style guides frown upon excessive subclassing. There is a reason why pylint's default configuration will complain about classes without at least a few methods. Python has enough more light-weight methods to achieve the same. As you've said it yourself, a factory function does the same job.

It's also somewhat awkward. Do you really want your users to create classes called something like `ListFromFile` and `ListFromString` instead of simple functions `make_list_from_file` and `make_list_from_string`?

Beyond simple style, there are functional reasons to consider:

1. A subclass would allow you to check the type information. Is this relevant? Probably not, but there are of course cases where you subclass for the simple purpose of creating a new type, e.g. exception classes
2. A subclass has higher runtime overhead. Especially method lookup will be slower.
3. Subclassing can lead to confusing behavior or may need additional care in programming. For example, let's say you want to implement `__getitem__(self, slice)` and like Python's list, return a copy of the given slice (like `list[0:10]`). Will the copy be an instance of your base class or your subclass? If it is an instance of the subclass, how do you make sure the init method accepts the correct parameters? If it will be an instance of the base class, any other overwritten behavior will be gone.

I suggest the following:

1. Create a simple and robust init method and tell people not to overwrite it, or only overwrite it with the same arguments
2. Use classmethods as additional constructors for certain types of arguments, e.g. from file, from python list, whatever
3. Advocate simple free-standing functions for simple cases
4. Suggest subclassing only when adding new behavior
5. Advocate adding new classmethods when adding new constructors for these complex cases

A last thought: Know your users. If yours are like mine, they are more familiar with structured programming using free functions and modules, not object oriented programming with inheritance. Of course, if your users are more familiar with OOP, maybe because you used to be a Java shop, the opposite may be true.

Addendum: As a case study where subclassing went wrong, look at numpy and its ndarray subclasses. Especially matrix and memmap. Try them sometime and see how far you come before something breaks because the semantics are not the same. If you pass a matrix to a function, you probably want a matrix as your return value. But if you pass a memmap, you cannot do this because you can't simply create a new memmap. Now you also have to think hard at every function whether you want to sanitize your input with `np.asarray` or `np.asanyarray` and know the different semantics that you may or may not invoke.

If even the numpy folks messed this up, how likely are you and your users getting it right?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favor on using the class as you can extend its functionality like adding methods that could be helpful to the users.

```
class List:
    pass


class GenerateList(List):
    def __init__(self, n, x, repeat=True):
        super().__init__()
        if repeat:
            self.listitems = [x] * n
        else:
            self.listitems = list(range(n, x+1))

    def get_even(self, flip=False):
        ret = [v for v in self.listitems if v%2 == 0]
        return ret if not flip else ret[::-1]

    def get_odd(self, flip=False):
        ret = [v for v in self.listitems if v%2 != 0]
        return ret if not flip else ret[::-1]

# Request a repeated list.
m = GenerateList(3, 2, repeat=True)
repeatlist = m.listitems

# Request a list in a range.
a = GenerateList(1, 10, repeat=False)
mylist = a.listitems
mylistodd = a.get_odd()
mylisteven = a.get_even(flip=True)

print(repeatlist)
print(mylist)
print(mylistodd)
print(mylisteven)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```